# How can I group elements based on their attributes in Jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, html, web, multi-select

I'm currently trying to create a button that allows me to group options based on an attribute. Since I'm no jquery wiz, I took the existing and working button "Add-all" and started modifying it in order to add only the options with a certain attribute. The following code is that intent...

```
this.container.find(".remove-all").click(function() {
  that._populateLists(that.element.find('option').removeAttr('selected'));
  return false;
});

this.container.find(".add-all").click(function() {
  var options = that.element.find('option').not(":selected");
  if (that.availableList.children('li:hidden').length > 1) {
    that.availableList.children('li').each(function(i) {
      if (jQuery(this).is(":visible")) jQuery(options[i - 1]).attr('selected', 'selected');
    });
  } else {
    options.attr('selected', 'selected');
  }
  that._populateLists(that.element.find('option'));
  return false;
});

this.container.find(".add-auto").click(function() {
  var options = that.element.find('option').not(":selected");
  if (that.availableList.children('li:hidden').length > 1) {
    that.availableList.children('li').each(function(i) {
      if (jQuery(this).is(":visible") && jQuery(this).has.class("auto")) jQuery(options[i - 1]).attr('selected', 'selected');
    });
  } else {
    that.availableList.children('li').each(function(i) {
      if (jQuery(this).has.class("auto")) jQuery(options[i - 1]).attr('selected', 'selected');
    });
  }
  that._populateLists(that.element.find('option'));
  return false;
});
},
```

I'm currently using the has.class in order to look for the attribute that i want. In this case , auto. But it's not working. I'm trying to fix the code shown on top, in order to call the attribute "auto". the `label = "'+ option.attr('class')+'"` is the code that generates the lable = "auto" in html.

```
_getOptionNode: function(option) {
  option = jQuery(option);
  var node = jQuery('<li class="ui-state-default ui-element "  title="' + option.text() + '" data-selected-value="' + option.val() + '" label = "' + option.attr('class') + '"  ><span class="ui-icon"/>' + option.text() + '<a href="#" class="action"><span class="ui-corner-all ui-icon"/></a></li>').hide();
  node.data('optionLink', option);
  return node;
},
```

Below there is an image that shows the user interface. When I inspect the AUTO: option , i have the following code...

```
<li class="ui-state-default ui-element  ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" title="AUTO: Car Dealers - New Cars (CARD_NEW)" data-selected-value="82" industry="auto'" style=""><span class="ui-helper-hidden"></span>AUTO: Car Dealers - New Cars (CARD_NEW)<a href="#" class="action"><span class="ui-corner-all ui-icon ui-icon-plus"></span></a></li>
```

[image: User Interface]

I want my Add auto button to be able to move all industry = "auto" options to the left.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal/simple js and html code and what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Can I ask for a code with comments please?

Comment: Also why are you hiding some sample data? are you really showing data that is in production?

Answer (score 0):

I am just going to base my answer on your **Title**

`var elements = $(document).find("[data-attribute]")`

that code is going to return all elements with an attribute of `"data-attribute"`

just change `document` if you want to find on specific places like inside of `div#Header` ... also change `data-attribute` to what you want like `industry` or `title` or even `data-selected-value`